# React MaterialUI DataGrid changing sort ToolTip text

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, tooltip

Is there a simple way to change the tooltip text when you hover over the sorting icon in the MaterialUI DataGrid component? I would like to be able to change the text from 'sort' to something else, maybe in a foreign language.

[image: MUI DataGrid sort tooltip text]

I have tried looking for a simple solution but could not find one anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `localeText` prop of the table as an object to override the texts.

[Here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/next/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/constants/localeTextConstants.ts) is the list of overrides.

In your case it would be

```
localeText={{columnHeaderSortIconLabel: 'Sortieren'}}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it must have been somewhere but I just couldn't find it.

Comment: No problem. If that answers your question, could you meet it as accepted so others can find it?